# Cakephp: AuthComponent Evaluation Order and how to redirect to an action

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.6

good day everyone, regarding auth component I am doing some tests to understand better the tool, in a probe of concept i want that an authenticated admin user be authorized to access any action, but if the authorized user has the "supervisor" role only be able to the actions index, view and edit in the "RequestsController.php", I am trying this approach:
1) allow everything for admin role and deny everything for anyone else in AppController.php.
2) Allow explicitly "supervisor" in "RequestsController.php" and deny any other role.

The doubt is that after some tests what happens is that if I authorize the admin user just in AppController.php the redirects only allows me to go to /webroot/, but If I allow the admin role in RequestsController.php. I can see requests without problem

### IsAuthorize method in AppController

```
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        //privileges 1 means admin
        if ($user['privileges']==1){
            debug($user);
            return true;
        } else {
            debug($user);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

### IsAuthorize method in Requests Controller

```
    public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        //privileges 9 means supervisor
        if ($user['privileges']==9){
            debug($user);
            $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
            if (in_array($action, ['index', 'view', 'edit'])) {
                debug($user);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            debug($user);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

As I am not clear in the order that the isAuthorized function is handled, or why the redirect to the Request (even if it is "AppController.php" or "RequestsController.php") So this makes me think that I'll have to explicity authorize the admin role in all controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ControllerAuthorize`, `AuthComponent` will call `isAuthorized()` method only on **active** controller. So, in your example, when requesting any action from `RequestsController`, only `RequestsController::isAuthorized()` will be called, disallowing access to users which has priviledge other than 9.

If you want to allow admin users to access as well, you should change your `RequestsController::isAuthorized()` as follows:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    //privileges 9 means supervisor
    if ($user['privileges']==9){
        debug($user);
        $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
        if (in_array($action, ['index', 'view', 'edit'])) {
            debug($user);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        debug($user);
        return parent::isAuthorized($user); //changed this line
    }

}
```

Additional info: [CakePHP 3.x AuthComponent - Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization)